# Send tar output and multiple commands over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to pass the output of a tar command and multiple commands which handle the tar stream over ssh ... something like this

```
tar -zcf - foo | ssh $host << EOF
tar -xf -
do-something-with-foo
do-other-things
EOF
```

doesn't work but is this somehow possible?

Comment: this one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553960/388449) does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything up in a generated script that you pass to the remote host.

```
{
        echo 'uudecode -o- <<EOT | tar -xzf-'
        tar -czf- foo | uuencode -m foo
        echo EOT
        echo do-something-with-foo
        echo do-other-things

} | ssh -T $host
```

The echo output will be run on the remote host, the `tar | uuencode`
runs locally.  The purpose of the uuencode is so that we can wrap the output into a heredoc on the remote end, bypassing the need for severe file descriptor juggling.

Comment: Thanks, this works so fare. Personally I like the 2nd version in the linked [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553960/388449) a bit more since it doesn't mix the two inputs and doesn't require a extra decode/encode on the tar stream.